# Wagtail Inlinepanel demo erorr

Tags: wagtail

I am relatively new to Django Wagtail and I was following the demo from the docs.wagtail.io website which can be found [here](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.8.1/reference/pages/panels.html?highlight=inlinePanel#inline-panels) on how to add a list of Links to a Page using an InlinePanel with Related links 
I seem to have reached an error that I donot fully understand it's meaning.
The error says

`AttributeError: type object 'BookPageRelatedLinks' has no attribute 'rel'`

**The code for the demo is as follows**

```
from wagtail.wagtailcore.models import Orderable, Page
from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey
from wagtail.wagtailadmin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel,InlinePanel
from django.db import models



class BookPage(Page):
  # The abstract model for related links, complete with panels
  class RelatedLink(models.Model):
      title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
      link_external = models.URLField("External link", blank=True)

      panels = [
          FieldPanel('title'),
          FieldPanel('link_external'),
      ]

      class Meta:
          abstract = True

  # The real model which combines the abstract model, an
  # Orderable helper class, and what amounts to a ForeignKey link
  # to the model we want to add related links to (BookPage)
  class BookPageRelatedLinks(Orderable, RelatedLink):
      page = ParentalKey('demo.BookPage', related_name='related_links')

  content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
    InlinePanel('BookPageRelatedLinks', label="Related Links"),
  ]
```

**My primary objective was to learn this so I can add image links to a sidebar on a BlogPage app I am developing.**

Comment: What versions of Django, Wagtail and the `django-modelcluster` package do you have installed? (You can find out by running `pip freeze` and looking for the relevant lines)

Comment: version 1.8.1 ,  I used `pip install wagtail` to get it , I assumed it was the latest

Comment: OK, that's the version of Wagtail - what about Django and `django-modelcluster`?

Comment: `Django==1.10.5`
`django-modelcluster==2.0`

Answer (score 2):

Your `InlinePanel` declaration isn't quite correct - it needs to be:

```
InlinePanel('related_links', label="Related Links")
```

Here's what's going on:

- By defining a ParentalKey with `related_name='related_links'`, you set up a one-to-many relation called `related_links` on BookPage. This allows you to retrieve all of the `BookPageRelatedLinks` objects associated with a given BookPage instance (for example, if your BookPage instance was called `page`, you could write `page.related_links.all()`).
- The `InlinePanel` declaration then tells Wagtail to make the `related_links` property editable within the admin.

The reason you're getting a misleading error message is that you've defined the `RelatedLink` and `BookPageRelatedLinks` classes inside the `BookPage` - which is a little bit unusual, but still valid. This results in `BookPageRelatedLinks` being defined as a property of BookPage (i.e. `BookPage.BookPageRelatedLinks`). Then, when Wagtail tries to set up the InlinePanel, it retrieves that property and fails because it's not the expected type of object (it's a class definition, not a relation).

If you write your models file in the more conventional way, with the related models defined below (or above) `BookPage`:

```
class BookPage(Page):
    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        InlinePanel('BookPageRelatedLinks', label="Related Links"),
    ]


# The abstract model for related links, complete with panels
class RelatedLink(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    link_external = models.URLField("External link", blank=True)

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('title'),
        FieldPanel('link_external'),
    ]

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


# The real model which combines the abstract model, an
# Orderable helper class, and what amounts to a ForeignKey link
# to the model we want to add related links to (BookPage)
class BookPageRelatedLinks(Orderable, RelatedLink):
    page = ParentalKey('home.BookPage', related_name='related_links')
```

...then you would get a more informative error: `AttributeError: type object 'BookPage' has no attribute 'BookPageRelatedLinks'`.

Comment: and how do I find a solution in that scenario when the error is that one because that error is the first error I got before I started tweaking my code and defining the Related Link class inside the BookPage class

Comment: Again, the fix is to use `InlinePanel('related_links', label="Related Links")`.